# How to find an event in EventStore by it Id?

Tags: eventstoredb

Currently I'm using Eventstore (by Greg Young) for my company project. In my read model, I store the processed event ids, not the event name. How can I find the event in Eventstore using its Id?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible currently. I think you have two choices:

in your read model store the stream and index, or the commit/prepare position of the event and then read the event from either the `$all` stream using the commit/prepare position or from the stream it was written to using the stream and index. This is probably the simplest.

Or create a projection in event store which indexes the events by their id and reprojects into a stream called, say, `eventid-{event.id}` then you can read directly from this stream.

The second is backwards compatible with your current read model, but I'm not sure is the right thing to do, as projections cause write amplification, and you probably need to make sure you exclude system events from being projected.

Comment: Actually I stored the event Ids just to avoid duplicated processing, but then sometimes I wanted to know the whole contents of them for troubleshooting. I haven't thought about storing event positions, thanks for that idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the event using the following URL path. This will return the event and the last 20 events before it

{youreventstoredomain}:2113/web/index.html#/streams/$ce-{streamname}/{eventnumber}/backward/20

Comment: This did not work form me. Looks like in the pattern you have suggested `{eventid}` is the ordinal number of the event in the stream, as opposed the event Guid that EventStore generates when the event is created.

Comment: That's correct @user1007074 sorry I was referencing the integer index value rather than the unique identifer. I'll update the name as it shouldn't be called EventID as that is the guid